# Why are graphics engines writen in C/C++, when games are GPU bound?

Tags: c++, gpu

What performance benefits a low level language can give to the engine, when the game is dependent on the GPU?

Comment: This question really lacks acceptability of premises. A lot of the games I know are CPU bound.

Comment: Maybe they would be CPU bound otherwise ;-)

Comment: Even with a GPU bound game (and not all are) using less CPU cycles is a good idea. Worst case the game is slightly faster and use less power. Best case is on a APU with a shared heat budget for the CPU and the GPU part, thus allowing the GPU parts to run faster.

Comment: What do you base this on? this is not true.

Comment: Evidence to the contrary: Dwarf fortress. Or any other heavy simulation game.

Comment: @Tordin which part. The speed or the budget. Speed is easy. Compare driving people around to a remote distance. Getting in and out of the car is done via the CPU. Driving via the GPU. Say I get in the car in 1 minute, drive for an hour and get out (onother minute), then the travling (program) is mostly limited by the distance traveled. Getting a faster car (better GPU performance or better GPU implementation) will speed things up. But even reducing the time needed to get in and out of the car will speed things up. There is just not much to be gained there. But that does not mean is is wasted,

Comment: nor that it needs no attention. If you both that and you somehow need an hour to get in and out of the car then we are back at Danijar's comment.

Comment: As to heat/power limited. Many chips now come with a traditional CPU part and a GPU part on board. The CPU parts (both Intels and AMDs) can turbo boost and thus speed up the game if there is sufficient heat budget. But that heat and the access to the main memory needs to be shared between the GPU and CPU parts. Optimising one leaves more room for the other.

Comment: There's a saying that 10% of the code takes 90% of the time; in many cases, the ratio is even more extreme. A game that's written 100% in C and/or C++ without using any GPU operations may be very slow, but writing a few dozen lines of assembly code to access the GPU may provide an orders-of-magnitude speedup.  If a vendor-supplied GPU library includes the necessary assembly code, it may be possible to write the remainder of the project in C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generalize that *"games are GPU bound"*. I assume that there are many engines out there for the other case. Otherwise what would we need [GPGPU techniques](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU) like CUDA or compute shaders for? They outsource computations from the CPU to the GPU.

But speaking for engines for which your statement is correct, there can be several reasons to choose low level programming languages like C or C++.

Games are written in these languages since many years. Therefore you have plenty of game development related libraries available. Moreover, these low level languages are industry standard. Therefore professional developers use them in most of their projects. If a company want to sell a game, there is no time to train the whole team in a new language.

Another reason can be that these developers just prefer these languages because they know them well. Why should a experienced game developer start using Python for his new engine if it is slower and he is already an expert in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Graphic APIs like OpenGL or Direct3d traditionally have APIs which are quite data-driven. They expect to be fed with vertices and textures as arrays of Plain-Old-Data.

A programming language like C (and as an extension C++), which is also very close to the actual representation of the data in memory and doesn't abstract it as much as, for example, Java or Python, have a design philosophy which is much more closer to that of these APIs. As a result, the interface between graphics API and program code usually feels more natural in C/C++. This allows to use them much more efficiently without creating too unreadable code.